# Failure of a large database export backup

Tags: oracle, backup, tibero

Currently, I need to make daily export backup of about 1 terabyte of tables.

The DBMS is called 'Tibero' which is made and used in Korea that is almost similar to Oracle.

Most of the time it runs fine, but one table is causing problems periodically.

This table is huge, taking up about 500GB, and if I can't find a solution, I will discuss deleting some of the data. (Expect it to be difficult)

The table also has 2 Clob columns and is adding 5-10 rows per second.

Looking at the export log and sys log, I see the error message 'Snapshot is too old' when an extract is in progress for this table.

I've tried increasing the size of the UNDO table and increasing the UNDO retention time, expecting that data will continue to be inserted while the export backup is running and that it will accumulate in the UNDO table, but the problem still exists.

Are there any other things I should consider or check for in order to export backup a large database?